# Convert InputStream to Java/Scala object

Tags: java, scala, serialization

While reading from InputStream, how do I convert the InputStream to a java/scala object? An example use case being, receive a CSV file as stream and parse the CSV row by row, on the fly.

For example: I have

```
case class Row(v1: String, v2: String, v3: String)
```

and a sample CSV file's single row is (Andy, Morgan, Male). Now suppose I receive this CSV InputStream and this CSV has millions of rows and can't be held into memory. Is it possible to cast the InputStream to the above mentioned case class, use it for my purpose, discard the instance of this case class and repeat this process for the entire stream.

A vague example would be on the lines of:

```
try( val inputstream = new FileInputStream("file.txt") ) {
  var data = inputstream.read();
  while(data != ???){
    ////// somehow convert/buffer the data and convert to Row class mentioned above
    data = inputstream.read();
  }
}
```

I want to understand the internals, so I'd be very thankful to a solution in native java/scala without any 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Can I know why this is downvoted? Is the question not clear enough and/or duplicate and/or homework?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but i assume there are some unclear points in your question:
1. InputStream is already a java\scala object, what could be the point of converting it
2. Parsing means creating data objects from structured text. So how the text is structured and what kind data objects you need as result
3. Why could any preliminary file writing be needed for this task?
As you could see my comment is longer than your question. Be more descriptive, supply us with some your code

Comment: ~Odomontis I've updated the question a bit. Does it still seem incomplete/confusing? Thanks for the input.

Comment: The steps, for a CSV file, are straightforward: 1. read characters rather than bytes (so use a Reader rather than an InputStream); 2. read one line after each other; 3. for each line, split the line into entries and create a Java object containing the information of the line, 4. do whatever you want with the object, 5, read the next line and repeat, until the end of file is reached.

Comment: Well, that's not the point. Consider I have a excel file getting streamed and I can parse it through something like Apache POI. In that case, I can't read the file character by character.

Comment: Found this http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/how-to.html#sxssf. Apparently in such cases it boils down to extract text etc from the document knowing the low level details and then user BufferedReader to read them on the fly.

Answer (score 0):

There's actually a Java inputstream called `ObjectInputStream` that you could use for this exact purpose of casting as a class.

```
try{
    val fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("file.txt")
    val objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(fileInputStream)
    var data = objectInputStream.readObject.asInstanceOf[Row]
    while(data != ???){
        /*Do stuff here*/
        data = objectInputStream.readObject.asInstanceOf[Row]
    }
}catch{
     /*Catch cases*/
}
```

Of course this assumes that your inputStream is streaming these `Row` objects, otherwise you'd have to go about this differently. If the file is to big to fit in memory to begin with, you may want to consider streaming these `Row` objects rather than to do this on the receiving end.

I did, however find this [class](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Development-Class/CSVfilereader.htm), which seems fairly versatile that has constructors like so (among many others):

```
CSVFileReader(File f) /*or*/ CSVFileReader(String filename, CSVFormat format)
```

There is a method to read in by line (`readLine()` which returns a `CSVLine`) which may help you in converting to the `Row`object.

Hope this helps!